# WebSocket connection to 'wss://mydomain.com:3001/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

### em-websocket configration in rails 2.3.18 and ruby 0.9.2

The application is hosted on the https: & http: sebsocket is working on the the staging(http://) domain but when we shifted it to the  https:// the websocket closed automatically after same time. And encounter the the following error in webconsole

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://my_domain.com:3001/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED
```

## websocket.ym

```
 production:
   host: '0.0.0.0'
   port: 3001
   secure: true
   tls_options:
     private_key_file: filename.com.key
     cert_chain_file: filename.com.crt
```

## websockets-app/app.rb

#### em-websocet configuration file location

"application_directory/websockets-app/app.rb" and it contains the following configuration

```
require 'thin'
require 'em-websocket'
require 'yaml'
require 'active_support/core_ext/hash'

env          = ENV['WS_ENV'] || :development
logfile      = File.open('../log/websocket.log', 'a')
logfile.sync = true
WS_LOGGER    = Logger.new(logfile)
CONFIG       = YAML.load_file('../config/websocket.yml').with_indifferent_access[env]
EM.run do
    WS_LOGGER.info("Starting WebSockets server on port #{CONFIG[:port]}")
    @channel = EM::Channel.new
    WS_LOGGER.info("ENV:- #{env}")
    WS_LOGGER.info("CHANNEL:-----+#{@channel.inspect}")
  #EM::WebSocket.start(:host => '0.0.0.0', :port => '3001') do |ws|
  EM::WebSocket.start(CONFIG) do |ws|
    WS_LOGGER.info("Socket started----")
    WS_LOGGER.info("Socket inspect#{ws.inspect}")

    ws.onopen do |handshake|
    WS_LOGGER.info("HANDSHAKE:---WS open now!!")
    WS_LOGGER.info("handshake.secure? ..... #{handshake.secure?}")
      sid = @channel.subscribe { |msg| ws.send msg }
    WS_LOGGER.info("<#{sid}> WebSocket connection open")

      ws.onclose do
    @channel.unsubscribe(sid)
    WS_LOGGER.info("<#{sid}> Connection closed")
      end

      ws.onmessage do |msg|
    @channel.push msg
    WS_LOGGER.info("<#{sid}> Received Message: #{msg}")
      end
   end
  end
end
```

### Start the websocket in production mode

```
WS_ENV=production bundle exec thin start -R app.rb &
```

### Check the logs

```
Starting WebSockets server on port 3001
I, [2015-12-03T20:50:25.588306 #4861]  INFO -- : ENV:- production
I, [2015-12-03T20:50:25.588341 #4861]  INFO -- : CHANNEL:-----+#   <EventMachine::Channel:0x315e908 @uid=0, @subs={}>
I, [2015-12-03T20:50:53.723973 #4861]  INFO -- : Socket started----
I, [2015-12-03T20:50:53.724169 #4861]  INFO -- : Socket inspect#<EventMachine::WebSocket::Connection:0x315dee0 @secure=true, @tls_options=
{"private_key_file"=>"filename.com.key", "cert_chain_file"=>"filename.com.crt"}, @debug=false, @signature=4, @close_timeout=nil, @handler=nil, @secure_proxy=false, @options=   {"port"=>3001, "secure"=>true, "tls_options"=>{"private_key_file"=>"filename.com.key", "cert_chain_file"=>"filename.com.crt"}, "host"=>"0.0.0.0"}>
```

#### create the instance of webSocket in Javascript ###

```
host = "wss://mydomain.com:3001"; socket = new WebSocket(host);
```

Comment: It's work perfact in http

Comment: What does the server log say?

Comment: @dan, it says the socket start on port number 3001 when we start it with following command "WS_ENV=production bundle exec thin start -R app.rb &" 
and rest are the inspected element that is passed  to the  "EM::WebSocket.start(CONFIG)", in CONFIG hash

Comment: and it closed after some time, in https:// environment, But it works fine in http://

Comment: What server log are you checking in?

Comment: What i think its related to the wss configuration in application, for that we need to configure socket for https environment.

Comment: And we can access the web-socket with ws for http:// and wss for https://

socket = new WebSocket("ws://.....") for http 

socket = new WebSocket("wss://.....") for https

Answer (score 0):

#### Why using SSL/TLS *should* fail (leave it to the proxy)

Most proxies and production application "wrappers" (i.e., Heroku Dynos) decrypt any SSL data before forwarding it to the handling application.

i.e., when using nginx as a proxy for SSL connections, the certificate and encryption is usually managed by nginx **and the data is sent to the local application as clear-text**.

The answer to your question should be to use clear-text for your app and have the local proxy deal with the SSL/TLS encryption.

#### To prove my point:

Since I don't like `em-websocket` (i'm biased towards my own pet project),  here's a quick [Plezi](http://www.plezi.io) application with and without a self-signed SSL certificate.

Running this application in a normal production environment (i.e. nginx, apache, Heroku, etc') should show that the application is accessible both using `https` and `http` when not secure and it isn't accessible when the application itself requires an encrypted connection.

`GEMFILE`:

```
gem 'plezi'
```

`app.rb`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'plezi'
class MyDemo
  # Http demo
  def index
     request.ssl? ? "Hello World (SSL/TLS)" : "Hello World (clear)"
  end
  # Websocket echo
  def on_message data
     write data # writes to the websocket
  end
end
route '/', MyDemo
```

Run the app with clear text:

```
./app.rb -p $PORT
# or static port, i.e.
# ./app.rb -p 3000
```

Run the app for encrypted connections:

```
./app.rb -p $PORT ssl
# or static port, i.e.
# ./app.rb -p 3000 ssl
```

If you setup your production proxy or Heroku Dyno (or whatever you're using) properly, the application should work for `http`, `https`, `ws`, and `wss` only when it's in clear-text mode and it should always fail when in SSL mode.

P.S.

It's possible to setup SSL keys and certificates within the app, to avoid a self-signed certificate, just in case you're wondering or think this is the issue. Add the following lines to your app:

```
Plezi.ssl_context.cert = IO.binread("filename.com.crt")
Plezi.ssl_context.key = IO.binread("filename.com.key")
```

Also, I'm Plezi's author, so I'm somewhat biased where em-websockets is concerned...